# how to use sed command properly to replace values containing / delimiter

Tags: linux, shell, sed

File: abc.properties

```
tomcat.home=/opt/tomcat
```

Set to /usr/local/tomcat. Following cmd is working.

```
sed -i "/tomcat.home=/ s/=.*/="usr\\/local\\/tomcat"/" abc.properties
```

Set to $WORKSPACE/tomcat. Following cmd is NOT working since value of the $WORKSPACE is having / delimeters.

```
sed -i "/tomcat.home=/ s/=.*/="$WORKSPACE\\/tomcat"/" abc.properties
```

Anyone has an idea how to success above cmd.

Thank you and appreciate your support...

Comment: Use a different delimiter? Say `@`?  `sed -i 's@/tomcat.home=@/usr/local/tomcat@' abc.properties`

Comment: It solved my problem & Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed lets you use any character you want as the delimiter. Whatever follows the `s` is used as the separator:

```
sed -Ee 's/foo/bar/'
sed -Ee 's|foo|bar|'
sed -Ee 's@foo@bar@'
```

^- All of those are equivalent.

The other option is to escape all your `/` as `\/`, but that gets nightmarish fast. Prefer to just pick a separator character that doesn't collide with characters you're trying to use for something else.

Comment: The routine use of `-E` is misdirected here (the regular expressions don't contain anything where it would matter) and is not portable (some `sed` variants use `-r` instead, some don't support it at all).

Comment: If you have no control over the input, finding a separator character which cannot occur in the input is much more nightmarish than figuring out how to properly escape the separator in the value. If you have Bash, `${variable//\/\\/}` obscurely but conveniently obtains the value of `variable` with slashes backslash-escaped. (Though for complete coverage, you should also backslash-escape any backslashes.)

Comment: It solved my problem & Thanks a lot...